# Construct triangle from three points on base and difference in distances to third vertex

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Imagine such a triangle:

[image: Diagram]

We know the differences in distances: $\overline{OA} - \overline{BO}$ and $\overline{CO} - \overline{BO}$, as well as the distances between the points on the base: $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{BC}$.

How do we solve for the triangle (or the point $O$ relative to any of the point $A$, $B$, or $C$)?

And beyond this, is there a solution that is computationally simple (e.g. fast to compute in a program)?

Comment: given two fixed points $A, B,$ the point $P$ such that $AP - BP = const$ describes a hyperbola with $A, B$ as foci. now find the common points of the two hyperbolas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given distances $OA-OB=p,\ OC-OB=q,\ AB=n,\ BC=m$,
solve the triangle $\triangle OAC$.

[image]

To solve the triangle $\triangle OAC$
it is sufficient to find $OB$, let's call it $r$,
since it is a radius of the circle centered at (yet unknown)
point $O$ that passes through the points $P,\,B,\,Q$.

[Stewart's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cevian)
is of a great help here,
it helps to bind a radius $r$ with the known
values $p,q,m$ and $n$ simply as 
\begin{align}
m(r+p)^2+n(r+q)^2=(m+n)(r^2+m n),
\end{align}
which gives a neat expression for the radius:
\begin{align}
r&=\frac{1}{2} \frac{m n (m+n)-m p^2-n q^2}{m p+n q}.
\end{align}

Comment: A very nice solution. Elegant and simple. Thanks!